# Laravel 5: The difference between Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($user); and auth()->login($user);

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

What is the difference between:

```
Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($user);
```

and

```
auth()->login($user);
```

? For example, in PasswordController.php we can have:

```
protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
{
    $user->password = $password;

    $user->save();

    Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($user);
}
```

or

```
protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
{
    $user->password = $password;

    $user->save();

    auth()->login($user);
}
```

(in this case, we create a mutator in *Users.php* to bcrypt password AND NOT in *resetPassword($user, $password)* as it is by default)

In particular, what is guard($this->getGuard()), what does it do (guard(), getGuard())?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference, the `auth` function is just a helper that returns an instance of `\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard`.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php