# Checking which `guard` is loggedin

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-authentication

I have a multiauth laravel 5.2 app, with the fallowing guards defined on `config/auth.php`:

```
...
'admin' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'admin',
],
'user' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'user',
],
...
```

So, `admin` and `user`.

The problem resides in the view layer, since this two loggedin guards share some views, ex:

```
Hello {{Auth::guard('admin')->user()->name}}
```

In this case the guard is hardcoded into the view to be always `admin` (it gives error when loggedin guard is `user`), but, to avoid have to do another equal view just for this little change, I would like have it dinamic, something like:

```
Hello {{Auth::guard(<LOGGEDIN GUARD>)->user()->name}}
```

PS: I know that this could be achieved getting the corresponding url segment, ex: `www.site.com/pt/user/dasboard` which in the case it would be segment 2, but this way the app would lose scalability, since in the future the corresponding segment may not be the same (2 in the example above)

Comment: Have a look [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2a38acf7ee2882d831a3b9a1361a710e70ffa31e/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L218) at `getGuard()` and how it's implemented in Laravel's `auth` area. Think that will get you going in right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately `Auth::guard($this->getGuard())` triggers `Method [getGuard] does not exist.` . I guess it's a 5.1 feature, i also checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624561/laravel-5-the-difference-between-authguardthis-getguard-loginuser , with same result

Comment: Right, since you're not in the auth class and the method is `protected`, you can't use `$this` to access it. But you might be able to access with something like `Auth::guard(Auth::getGuard())` but I'm not positive.

Comment: also didn't work, `...class 'Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard' does not have a method 'getGuard'`

Answer (score 75, accepted):

One way to do this is to extend the Laravel authentication class in the IoC container to include, for instance, a `name()` method that check which guard is used for the current session, and calls `user()` on that Guard instance.

Another way is to simply use an *if-statement* in your Blade template:

```
@if(Auth::guard('admin')->check())
    Hello {{Auth::guard('admin')->user()->name}}
@elseif(Auth::guard('user')->check())
    Hello {{Auth::guard('user')->user()->name}}
@endif
```

However, this is a little dirty. You can clean this up a bit by using a partial, or by passing the view a variable containing the guard name, either directly from your Controller, or via a ViewComposer, and then doing:

```
Hello {{Auth::guard($guardName)->user()->name}}
```

in your View.

Extending Laravel's authentication is your best option, imo.

Comment: Thanks but that also would remove scalability from the app since the I would be fixed to the `admin/user` guard

Comment: Very true. That's why extending the Laravel authentication is the better option here.

Comment: @tomfrio what if you're logged as both?

Comment: return me : auth guard [user] is not defined ... but [admin] worked and return false for non admin new user

Answer (score 14):

This will get the guard name that is used for current logged in user

```
Auth::getDefaultDriver()
```

When you log in, by default it will get you the:

```
'web'
```

Dependable through which guard you've been logged in it will get you that guard name.

This is not applicable for APIs!!! Because APIs in laravel by default don't use session.

Comment: Auth::getDefaultDriver() is get $this->app['config']['auth.defaults.guard']; it should be always the config value

Comment: Not if you have multiple and are used dynamically... with that ^ you will get the default that is hard coded in config.auth file

Comment: This is the default driver from the config, not the the one that is used for current logged user

Answer (score 11):

Since Laravel 5.5, this is easy to do with the `@auth` template directive.

```
@auth("user")
    You're a user!
@endauth

@auth("admin")
    You're an administrator!
@endauth

@guest
    You're not logged in!
@endguest
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#if-statements

Comment: i tried with your answer, but when i login with auth('admin'),it show content of admin but it still shows content of guest, i dont know why?!

Answer (score 7):

In new versions of laravel use:

```
Auth::getDefaultDriver()
```

I recommend to use global helper function like

```
function activeGuard(){

foreach(array_keys(config('auth.guards')) as $guard){

    if(auth()->guard($guard)->check()) return $guard;

}
return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Depends of Harat answer, I built a Class names CustomAuth, and it give me easy access to Auth facade methods: `user()` and `id()`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Utils;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CustomAuth{
    static public function user(){
        return Auth::guard(static::activeGuard())->user() ?: null;
    }

    static public function id(){
        return static::user()->MID ?: null;
    }

    static private function activeGuard(){

        foreach(array_keys(config('auth.guards')) as $guard){

            if(auth()->guard($guard)->check()) return $guard;

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using `auth()->guard($guard)->getName()` will return two different type of values

> login_admin_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d

if is an admin guard

> login_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d

if is a web guard or depending on your use case a user guard. So you can test against that.

so a simple use case can be as stated below

```
 if(str_contains(auth()->guard($guard)->getName(), 'admin')){
      dd('is admin');
   }
```

here if is an admin, it will show `'is admin'` otherwise you get the default

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had up and running project with too often usage of `auth()->user()` thus I was obligated to find a way to keep using multiple guards across my app.

---

Use a middleware to handle overwriting the value the default guard.

Add a custom web middleware to your web group within `kernel.php`

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            .....
            //This cool guy here
            \App\Http\Middleware\CustomWebMiddleware::class,
        ],
```

Use `CustomWebMiddleware.php` content:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;


use Closure;

class CustomWebMiddleware
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $customGuard = 'custom-guard-name-goes-here';
        if (auth($customGuard)->check()) {
            config()->set('auth.defaults.guard', $customGuard);
        }

        // if you have multiple guards you may use this foreach to ease your work.
        /*$guards = config('auth.guards');
        foreach ($guards as $guardName => $guard) {
            if ($guard['driver'] == 'session' && auth($guardName)->check()) {
                config()->set('auth.defaults.guard', $guardName);
            }
        }*/

        return $next($request);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Auth::getDefaultDriver()
```

Above will return the current guard, in your case (user or admin)